# Import excel file in Angular and pass data into ASP.NET Core API project

Tags: c#, excel, file, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

So the situation is the following. I have an Angular front end project and I want to import an excel file from the front end together with some additional properties.

The front end I will handle, but I have a couple of questions for the back end:

1. What should I be receiving as a variable type in the back end for the excel file?
2. I want to foreach the data from the excel file and get only specific data. For example, I have one sheet only with rows Name, Age and Number of transactions. I want to take only the name and number of transactions and save that information in a new instance of a class I have within my application.

How do I do that?

Comment: depends what you are doing in the front end are you going to upload the file to asp, are you going to read the file into a js object and send the data that way, are you going to manipulate the data before sending it etc? If you are just going to upload the file then ASP will need setting up to read a stream which you can then pass into the to the open xml nugget package to process, this is because xlsx is a set of compressed XML files, if you are going to process the file in the frontend then you will be sending either XML or JSON to ASP which will then map it to an object you have configured

Comment: ASP File handling can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0#file-upload-scenarios Open XML SDK here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Comment: @MikeT On the front end I am only uploading the file and passing it to the controller. I don`t want to save that file anywhere, only to extract the data from it, assign it to a model and then save the information in the database

Comment: saving the file is a requirement even if its only to temp store that will be removed once you have finished with it, as it note on the link i provided "Any single buffered file exceeding 64 KB is moved from memory to a temp file on disk."

Answer (score 0):

required before you start the [OPEN XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#how-to-install-the-nuget-package)

First in asp you need to defined your method with a IFormFile variable or use the FileUpload Helper class

then you need to move the data into a stream eg IFormFile.CopyToAsync(Stream)

finally open the spreadsheet for read only access so you can read the data

this would look something like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUploadAsync(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    foreach(var file in files)
    {
        using var mem = new MemoryStream();
        await file .CopyToAsync(mem);
        var doc = SpreadsheetDocument Open(mem, false);
        ...
```

this will open the file and parse the data in it as an excel spreadsheet

you can then use the spreadsheet methods to extract the data you require from inside the document